# Navigating between screens based on the Provider value change in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I have a flutter application with BLE communication. I've put BLE-related variables and functions in a Provider class. My screens' structure is as follows:

```
Home -> ModeSelect -> NormalMode -> NormalDataShow

                   |

                   -> CustomMode -> CustomModeShow
```

The device which is under our control has pushbuttons as well. So whenever the user pushes a button, the BLE data should be discarded and the app should go to the ModeSelect screen.

So if we are in NormalDataShow or CustomMode screens, for example, and the user pushes the button, these screens should be closed and the app must go back to the ModeSelect automatically.

The device send a packet each time the user pushes the button. I currently receive this packet and can handle its value change in Provider class.

My question is that: How I can navigate between screens after such events?

I have tried this but everything is messed up and _*Failed assertion: line 1995 pos 12: '!*debugLocked'** error occurs:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _bleProvider = Provider.of<BLEProvider>(context, listen: true);
    if (_bleProvider.modeChanged == true) {
      _bleProvider.modeChanged = false;
      _bleProvider.resetScore();
  
      Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('mode');
      return Container();
    } else
      return ... // The page main scaffold
```

Comment: Are named routes a must? There's a pretty simple way to solve this if that isn't a hard requirement.

Comment: No actually it is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take an approach similar to the [BottomNavigationBar example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) from the Flutter team.

Basically, have a single `Scaffold` that changes its properties (primarily `body`) based on the value of your provider.

For example:

```dart
enum Page { a, b ,c }

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class BleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<Page, Widget> _widgets = {
    Page.a: Text('a'),
    Page.b: Text('b'),
    Page.c: Text('c'),
  };
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _bleProvider = Provider.of<BLEProvider>(context, listen: true);
    // Determine what page to show
    final page = Page.a;
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BLE App'),
      ),
      body: _widgets[page],
    );
  }
}
```

This is a simplified example but should help you get started.